# how to read different csv files with different schema in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a folder which contains SQL files(for schema) and zipped files (CSV files) I want to read files with the same schema into one data frame and so for different schema different data frames in `pyspark`.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
abc.sql
abc1.gz
abc2.gz
def.sql
def1.gz
def2.gz
```

and so on...

how can I proceed

Comment: How do we find out which schema file belongs to which csv files?

Comment: name of sql file is same as csv file .e.g.- abc.sql contains schema for abc.gz

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add the `inferSchema` parameter and set it to `True`:

```
data = spark.read.csv([DATA_PATH], inferSchema = True, header = True, sep = ";")
```

Comment: don't think this is helping me inferschema is not at all required as i have my schema defined in .sql file and need to get schema from those files only